# Getting Data from Multiple EditText after a click of single Button

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I'm totally new to this forum and need help from you guys. I've been developing an Android application to find the efficiency of an Induction Motor. I'm new to Android App developement so I need your help.

I've created the layout and I have multiple edit text to get the inputs from  the user, all I want to do is get the input from the edittext on the press of a single button. Can anyone help me with the java coding

The XML Part of the layout is as follows:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".StartingPoint" >

   <TextView 
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="THE EFFICIENCY IS 0" 
       android:gravity="center"
       android:textSize="25dp"      
       />

    <EditText 
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:hint="ENTER VOLTAGE"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:id="@+id/etVoltage"
       />

   <EditText 
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
       android:hint="ENTER CURRENT"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:id="@+id/etCurrent"
       />

   <EditText 
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:hint="ENTER FREQUENCY"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:id="@+id/etFrequency"
       />

   <EditText 
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:hint="ENTER STATOR PHASE RESISTANCE"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:id="@+id/etStatorresistance"
       />

   <EditText 
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:hint="ENTER NO LOAD POWER"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:id="@+id/etLoadpower"
       />

   <Button 
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text= "FIND EFFICIENCY"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:id="@+id/bFind"
       />

</LinearLayout>
```

The Java Part of the coding is StartingPoint.java

```
package com.blitzkrieg.vishwas;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class StartingPoint extends Activity {

    EditText current, voltage, frequency, loadpower, statorresistance; 
    Button find;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_starting_point);

        EditText current = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCurrent);
        EditText voltage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etVoltage);
        EditText frequency= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etFrequency);
        EditText loadpower= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etLoadpower);
        EditText statorresistance= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etStatorresistance);

        Button find = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bFind);
        find.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.starting_point, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Doubts that I've in my mind regarding this coding

1. Is the use of findViewbyId for edittext correct over here, I want to get the input values from the user using edit text.
2. Where in this Java coding shall I put the line of code to fetch the data from all the    editText.
3. I want to get the result that is the efficiency of the motor just with the press of a single button which "Find Efficiency" in case of this program.
4. Is the data entered into the editText automatically fetched after enterin the data in that edit Text or do I need to add some buttons for fetching the data?

Please Help me guys.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your code with this code.It think this code will do your job.

1.You have declared Edittext reference correctly but you dont have to again n again declared in your code.Before your onCreate() method referencing Editext is all right. This may give you quite a handle say global which you can use in your this class everywhere you want.Inside your onCreate() you write this;

EditText current = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCurrent);

But declaring like this you cannot get this EditText value inside a button or where ever because this EditText has limited scope.Write like this;

current = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCurrent);

2.When you click on button you wanna get the EditText values.You should have to do like below i have done inside onClick().

3.As i get values in String inside onClick().Show them in LogCat.Display it here the result.

4.When you click the button all the data in every EditText will you get in String.Now do whatever you want.

```
     package com.blitzkrieg.vishwas;

     import android.app.Activity;
     import android.os.Bundle;
     import android.util.Log;
     import android.view.Menu;
     
    import android.view.View;
     import android.widget.Button;
     import android.widget.EditText;

      public class StartingPoint extends Activity {

EditText current, voltage, frequency, loadpower, statorresistance; 
Button find;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_starting_point);

     current = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCurrent);
     voltage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etVoltage);
     frequency= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etFrequency);
     loadpower= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etLoadpower);
     statorresistance= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etStatorresistance);

    Button find = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bFind);
    find.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            /* This code get the values from edittexts  */
       String currentvalue = current.getText().toString();
       String voltagevalue = voltage.getText().toString();
       String frequencyvalue = frequency.getText().toString();
       String loadpowervalue = loadpower.getText().toString();
       String statorresistancevalue = statorresistance.getText().toString();
       
       /*To check values what user enters in Edittexts..just show in logcat */ 
       Log.d("currentvalue",currentvalue);
       Log.d("voltagevalue",voltagevalue);
       Log.d("frequencyvalue",frequencyvalue);
       Log.d("loadpowervalue",loadpowervalue);
       Log.d("statorresistancevalue",statorresistancevalue);
       
        }
    });
    }


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.starting_point, menu);
    return true;
}

   }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, now can you help me in implementing the formula? Suppose I'm finding out the copper loss and thas equal to (3*Current^2*Resistance) so how and in which part of the coding do I implement it? And later on I'll use the this value i.e copper loss to find other value.

Comment: Inside Onclick but After logcat..
 Double loss = Math.pow(3*Double.parseDouble(currentvalue), 2* Double.parseDouble(statorresistancevalue)) ;